# MySQL, order by dynamic field

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count sites on some languages for statistics and use this query:

```sql
SELECT `language_id` , count( * ) AS 'num'
FROM sites
WHERE `language_id` != 0
GROUP BY `language_id`
ORDER BY 'num' ASC
```

But result isn't ordered by `num` field. What is wrong in my SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are quoting your alias `num` using the single quote `'` character, which happens to be valid in creating the alias but is treated as a literal string in the `ORDER BY` clause: since it is invariant across the results it does not affect the sort order.  The backtick character is valid in both clauses.  Try instead:

```
SELECT `language_id` , count( * ) AS `num`
FROM sites
WHERE `language_id` != 0
GROUP BY `language_id`
ORDER BY `num` ASC
```

Comment: The confusing thing is OP's description _"result isn't ordered by num field"_ , AFAIK he shouldn't get any result in the first place, right?

Comment: @Adnan: The OP's query was ordering by an invariant string literal.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was referring to `AS 'num'`. Doesn't it generate an error?

Comment: @Adnan: No, [In the select list of a query, a quoted column alias can be specified using identifier or string quoting characters ... Elsewhere in the statement, quoted references to the alias must use identifier quoting or the reference is treated as a string literal.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: I'm with eggyal here :) +1 for seeing the quote issue !